# Observing from a black hole proximity

Tags: black-holes, time

Suppose that you could get close enough to a black hole that time slowed down significantly for you, and you looked at a giant clock back on earth through a telescope. Would you see the earth clock go faster than your handwatch?

Comment: But it is a typical Einstein Gedankenexperiment. Special relativity is usually derived using $c = \text{const}$ for all observers and observing clocks in other frames of reference!

Answer (score 2):

Why a black hole? Try earth, this very experiment has been done with precision atomic clocks, on at sea level and one in the mountains! When comparing the times shown on the clocks later, the one that was on the mountain advanced faster (cf. [experimental confirmation of gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation#Experimental_confirmation))!

This effect even has to be considered for the precision clocks in the GPS.

As the metric field outside of a spherically symmetric body follows the Schwarzschild solution, there is no qualitative difference between being close to and far from a black hole or earth. (Unless the black hole rotates, for earth the rotation effects (Lense-Thirring-effect/frame-dragging) also have been verified experimentally).